# Saving multiple attachments in database, phpmyadmin

Tags: php, upload

I am making a form to send an email with multiple attachments. And i m saving those multiple attachments in database also.
The problem is how to get the data of the attachments array, to save in database, I am using the following code:

```
$filesize = $_FILES['attachment']['size'][$key];
$extention = pathinfo ($_FILES['attachment']['name'][$key] ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
 $name=$_FILES['attachment']['name'][$key];
$data=file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']));
```

By this , i get the Size, Extension, Name of the files array, but not the data, it gives error.. How can i get the data of files array

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `[$key]` in the `file_get_contents()` line and have the name ( uploaded_file against attachment) wrong. Use this:

```
$filesize = $_FILES['attachment']['size'][$key];
$extention = pathinfo($_FILES['attachment']['name'][$key] ,PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
$name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'][$key];
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$key]));
```